# DisplayTemplate being ignored (covarient interface?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, display-templates

This is a weird one. I have the following view file (`Views/Search/Submit.cshtml`):

```
@model IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, ISearchProvider>>

@foreach (var provider in Model)
{
    var results = provider.Value.Results.Take(10);

    if (results.Count() > 0)
    {
        <text><li class="dropdown-header">@provider.Key</li></text>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => results)   
    }
}
```

... where `results` is a `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<out T>`, and `T is ISearchMatch`.

I have then defined a display template in `Views/Search/DisplayTemplates/SiteSearchMatch.cshtml`;

```
@model SiteSearchMatch
<li>@Html.ActionLink(Model.Name, "details", "site", new { Id = Model.Id }, null)</li>
```

... and `SiteSearchMatch` implements `ISearchMatch` like so;

```
public class SiteSearchMatch: ISearchMatch
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I'd expect that my display template gets used; but it doesn't. Instead, the output I see being output is;

```
<li class="dropdown-header">sites</li>
11147166811481897189813271028
```

... where that string of numbers is the combination of all the `Id`s of the `ISearchMatch`'s I wanted to render via the display template.

It seems Razor is simply rendering the `ISearchMatch` using the first attribute defined in the class; if I remove the definition of the `Id` property, I instead see the combination of all the `Name`'s of the `ISearchMatch`'s.

---

Does anyone know why this is happening, and how I can get Razor to use the display template I've specified?

Comment: You can specify the display template using `@Html.DisplayFor(x => results, "SiteSearchMatch")`. I suspect you need to use the fully qualified name of `SiteSearchMatch` in your display template if you use the first overload of `@Html.DisplayFor()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *lame* answer is that the "Build Action" on my View file `Views/Search/DisplayTemplates/SiteSearchMatch.cshtml` was set to "None", rather than "Content".

This meant the code worked fine when running in Debug mode within Visual Studio, but didn't work when any *deployment* was made.

Just to reiterate; this fix required *no* code changes. Simply change the "Build Action" back to "Content".

Answer (score 1):

Your expectation is wrong:

> I'd expect that my display template gets used; but it doesn't.

The output you see is the ID's simply listed. I suspect your `ISearchMatch`-interface does only expose the `Id`-property, but this does not matter. What matters is the actual type of the instance of the result. In your case the following line:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => results)
```

can be implicitly evaluated as

```
HtmlHelper<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, ISearchProvider>>>
    .DisplayFor<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, ISearchProvider>>, IEnumerable<ISiteMatch>>
        (Func<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, ISearchProvider>>, IEnumerable<ISiteMatch>> expression);
```

Looks pretty complex, but basically it's just a implicit substitution of your model and expression result. Your model is of type `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, ISearchProvider>>`. That's also the type for the input of your lampda-expression. The result is of type `IEnumerable<ISiteMatch>`. And here come's the important thing!

The `DisplayFor` implementation checks, if the result type is enumerable or not. If not, it searches for a fitting template for the type, otherwise it will iterate through the elements and does this for all elements. <sup>1</sup>

Searching for a template works based on the type name. In your case the template uses the name of the enumerated type, which is `ISearchMatch`. It does not find any display template, so it simply dumps the properties, resulting in what you see:

```
11147166811481897189813271028
```

To fix this problem, you need to convert your result set to the correct type first. You can do this in different ways. Either you cast the whole result of your provider results:

```
var results = provider.Value.Results
    .Cast<SiteSearchMatch>()
    .Take(10);
```

or you cast them individually within your lamda expression:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => (SiteSearchMatch)results)
```

The important thing is, that the scalar result type is the same as the model in your display template.

<sup><sup>1</sup> Note that this is a little bit more complex, for example the the extension also keeps track of an index and applys it to the output, so that the model could be bound for postback purposes.</sup>

Comment: Humm, the problem is that `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, ISearchProvider>>` originally passed into the View has multiple `KeyValuePair`s, where each `ISearchProvider.Results` returns a different concrete implementation of `ISearchMatch`; I can't cast *all* of them to `SiteSearchMatch`, as I also have various `XSearchMatch` and `YSearchMatch`'s also being returned...

Comment: Then you either have to change your DisplayTemplate to display `ISearchMatch`, instead of the concrete types. The alternative is to switch display templates, based on the type of each entry (which you can request using `.GetType()`). However, the HtmlHelper extensions do not support inheritance.

Comment: I ended up using your `GetType()` hint to see what `Type` Razor was interpreting the items in the `IEnumerable<ISearchMatch>` as; it turns out it sees them as the concrete type they are rather then `ISearchMatch`'s as you hinted. This pointed me in the direction of the view not actually being loaded correctly, and I eventually uncovered [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23890352/1252702).